# LSI updater appears to have updated my Intel SSD, now cant recognise it - what to do?

Tags: intel, lsi, firmware

I have an LSI 9211 HBA and an Intel 910 SSD. I updated the firmware on the HBA, using LSI's usual sas2flash utility. I removed all other LSI/HBA cards first.

Unfortunately it now looks like the SSD also has the same controller internally, which I had no realistic way to know in advance, and now Intel's SSD toolkit won't recognise the SSD so I can't figure how to put it back as it was. Sas2flash -listall shows the SSD with P20 LSI bios.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the correct answer was *"talk to LSI, get told nothing will be done; talk to Intel, get told it can be replaced under warranty, send off 910 SSD, receive top-of-line P3700 in return"* :)

The answer above got the key point though which was to speak to Intel

Answer (score 3):

That's unfortunate.

The [Intel 910 PCIe SSD](http://www.thessdreview.com/our-reviews/intel-910-pcie-ssd-review-amazing-performance-results-in-both-400gb-and-800gb-configurations/) is comprised of multiple Intel SSDs behind an LSI2008 SAS controller. This is the same controller used by the LSI 9211 HBAs, so at some point in your flashing process, you were probably presented with a warning asking you which adapters should be flashed.

Did you ignore this? Did you just flash everything that came up during device discovery?

The best suggestion is to try to flash Intel software over the relevant card, or contact Intel support.

Comment: There wasn't any warning. If there had been, I'd have known immediately - and probably the updater would have aborted too. No warning - I checked I'd removed other HBAs and that my 9260 wasn't in there by mistake (I knew it wasn't but still checked), the only cards were an LSI HBA, an SSD and a Chelsio NIC, so I went ahead and updated. The command used for flashing is -fwall which flashes to all cards (and saves looking up a specific identifier when not needed), so its clearly important to remove any other HBAs and especially LSI cards, which I did. Nothing said "Intel card here, are you sure"